# Expectation of $\cos(\|X\|)$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$

Tags: integration, statistics, improper-integrals, estimation, parameter-estimation

Do:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2} + \frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2}\right]}\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}y
$$

This problem arises from an expectation of $\cos(\|X\|)$ where $X$ is a Gauss distributed.

Thank you!

Comment: Try transforming to polar coordinates first

Comment: Have already tried it, doesn't work, if I did it right way.

Comment: Here is an idea: if you convert to polar, then find a closed form for: 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty
 r^n \cdot
 \exp \left( 
   -\frac{1}{2} \left[
        \frac{ (r\cdot\cos(\theta)-\mu_x)^2 }{ {\sigma_x}^2 } +
        \frac{( r\cdot\sin(\theta)-\mu_y)^2} { {\sigma_y}^2 }
       \right]
   \right) 
   \mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta $$
... for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then you can use the Taylor series expansion of $\cos$, and see what that sum converges to.

Comment: Unfortunately, no finite series will provide good result in this case.